# XDMP-FORESTERR: Error in checkpoint of forest App-Services: SVC-FILWRT

Tags: marklogic

When trying to open query console getting the below error as seen in the images below:

[image]

Comment: It reads `No space left on device`. Make room, and restart affected cluster, hosts, or forests to recover.

Comment: @grtjn you should post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reads `No space left on device`. Make room, and restart affected cluster, hosts, or forests to recover.

HTH!